# Obtener "variables" en Swi Prolog

Tags: prolog

Tengo esta Base de Conocimiento

```
viveEn(dracula, castillo).
viveEn(godzilla, espacio).
viveEn(sullivan, espacio).
viveEn(mLegrand, tv).
maneja(godzilla, auto(4)).
maneja(barney, colectivo(fucsia,10,5)).
maneja(sullivan, nave([2,3,1]).
```

Y estoy realizando un ejercicio en el cual se solicita crear una regla donde un monstruo pueda llevar a otro monstruo pero solo si el primer monstruo "maneja" y ambos "viveEn" en el mismo lugar

**¿No hay una manera en la cual, envie el nombre del monstruo y me devuelva el lugar donde vive?**

<sub>PD: a la hora de hacerlo mediante consultas si se puede, pero haciendo la regla no.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así,

```prolog
taxista(Taxista, Pasajero) :-
    maneja(Taxista, _),
    viveEn(Taxista, Donde), viveEn(Pasajero, Donde).
```

Es necesario usar una variable auxiliar, *Donde*, para realizar '*ambos viven en el mismo lugar*'.